# Jquery sortable, div overflow not possible

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a sortable list with a few divs in it. One of those divs has a list with a scrollbar, the problem now is that i can't use the scrollbar because the draggable div.

Is it possible to block a certain part or complete div of moving?

Comment: could you post a code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the "handle" option to narrow what part of the div the user has to click in order to drag it. This has saved my butt a lot of times.

Comment: Ahh that's easy! Thank you very much